# Can someone help me diagnose what is wrong with my cactus and how do I treat it?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, cactus

[image]Does anyone know what is happening to my cactus.  It was a beautiful specimen when I got it and was fine for a year or so, but then it gradually started with the browning and weird skin disease.  It has been getting progressively worse and quicker to attack. It aslo seems to disfigure new grownth and existing growth.  Did start near bottom I think, but seems to attack quite quickly on new growth as well.  It's been in this spot for several years.  I tried neem oil last year, but didn't seem to work at all.  It continues to attack when I move a limb to a pot so I think it is systemic (?).

It is not as green as it was when I first planted or as green as the limb from it that I planted in a pot (see picture)  It is winter here in California.  Perhaps it doesn't like as much sun as it's getting.

[image][image]
[image][image][image]

Comment: Can you tell if any of these are scale insects? Can you pick one of the spots off and is there a bug undeneath? If so, you can use an insecticide, a systemic would probably be best. Otherwise it's probably fungal or bacterial infection. Sulphur or a commercial antifungal/antimicrobial product should work. It doesn't look like a desert setting, so this may be a constant battle  if you have high-ish humidity and limited airflow.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I will check for a bug and also move it to a dryer pot.